# How to erase an element from a vector<shared_ptr>

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I´m buiding a sort of a registry class using the following code:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public:
       int a;
       std::string b;
};

class Register
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> items;

        bool registerItem(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> item)
        {
            /*
             * Check if item exists
             */
            auto position = std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), item);

            if (position != items.end())
                return false;

            items.push_back(item);

            return true;
        }

         bool unregisterItem(std::shared_ptr<MyClass> item)
        {
            auto position = std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), item);

            if (position == items.end())
               return false;

            items.erase(item);

            return true;
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> item1 = new MyClass;

    Register registry;

    if (!registry.registerItem(item1))
        std::cout << "Error registering item1" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success registering item1" << std::endl;

    if (!registry.registerItem(item1))
        std::cout << "Error unregistering item1" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Success unregistering item1" << std::endl;
}
```

I can´t compile this code, as `items.erase(item)` complains about `error: no matching member function for call to 'erase'`.

Why I can´t erase the object I´ve added. What is the correct way to remove a `std::shared_ptr` from a `std::vector` ?

Comment: You erase *iterators*, not the value itself.

Comment: Using a vector for your registry could get expensive; as written, registering N items takes `O(N^2)` time. On the other hand, the inner loop is fast and the storage overhead minimal. Still, if you expected `N` to be big, you might want to think about a `std::unordered_set` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you want to use an iterator into `items` (*i.e.* `position`), so:

```
items.erase(position);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time on erase.

Answer (score 2):

There are two declarations available. [From cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/):

```
iterator erase (const_iterator position);
iterator erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

You try to `std::vector::erase` the item itsself instead of the iterator. Use

```
items.erase(position);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `erase` on `position`, not `item`
since erase is used on iterators

Answer (score 0):

You should pass  to erase iterator not a value, there is nothing special with deleting std::shared_ptr. Also you have mistype in code: you register item twice instead of unregister it in the second call.